# Changing registry without admin rights

Tags: windows, registry

I thought I needed admin rights for changing registry (I get errors if my app doesn't have such). Maybe only some part of the registry require admin rights.

Could you give some information? I need to store my app data somewhere without admin rights.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need administrative privileges to write to locations that are shared by multiple users.
In the filesystem, this means folders like `\WINDOWS` or `\Program Files`.
In the registry, this means all of the hives which aren't per-user.

Therefore, you can only write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.
Specifically, you should write to `HKCU\Software\Your Company`.

Comment: By "Specifically, you should write to HKCU\Software\Your Company" you mean that this is the only location you are able to write without administrative privileges, or that you can write everywhere under HKCU but this is the recommended thing to do?

Comment: Well, I thought the same too.But then I fell into this problem... In a win 7 64 machine, I run a setup msi, created by me in VS 2010, under a user account with no admin rights. In this msi, I was setting some registry values under HKCU... But it would not execute. It asked me for administrative rights. Removing the registry settings from the msi, everything went smooth, the application was installed, but without the settings in HKCU. I found this really weird, since everybody seems pretty sure you don't need admin rights under HKCU.By the way i was writing within my company's subkey too

Comment: Also, running the very same msi (the one with the registry settings) in another machine as a non-admin user, installed without problem (and no elevated prompts for admin). In the previous machine (win7 64), not only a simple user could not install it, but also when run under an admin account, the elevate prompt would open up, as if it needed admin rights. That would not happen in other machines with simple users. The app would install perfectly under non-admin users and without prompting for admin rights too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work. Writing to HKCU via C# still is requiring admin rights

Answer (score 9):

Log in as a normal non-admin user. Open up `regedit`, right-click on the top level keys and examine the permissions for each, you'll see which ones you can write to as a user. Basically, it's just `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844441/changing-registry-without-admin-rights/4844446#4844446) says.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is off limits, for instance. You can write to `HKEY_USERS/your users SID`, because `HKCU` is basically an image of that.

Comment: HKCU is an _alias_ to that.  They're backed by the same file on disk.

Comment: How does one run REGEDIT as a non-administrator? On Win10, REGEDIT always prompts for elevation, or for standard users, it asks for administrator credentials.

Comment: @UweBaemayr It works, the same way as you can run nearly every tool in the Admin tools list with a normal account.